# Google Cloud flexible query

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I try to make a query that retrieves entities with tag = "red" OR tag = "blue"

I can not do it like:

```
colors = ["red", "yellow"]
query.where("tag", "=", colors[0]).where("tag", "=", colors[1])
```

Is there a way to make it with a flexible 'OR' filter?

I was even considering string query like

```
query.query_string = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE tag = @1 OR tag = @2"
```

but [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference) says that:

> != and OR operators are not yet supported by Datastore
>   GQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!= and OR operators are not supported by the Ruby Google Cloud gem. You could mimic an OR operator by querying Cloud Datastore per OR'd statement and concatenating the results. Similar to the following code, **but not exactly because this code can contain duplicates**:

```
datastore = Google::Cloud::Datastore.new

red_query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
red_query.kind("messages").where("tags", "=", "red")
items = datastore.run red_query

yellow_query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
yellow_query.kind("messages").where("tags", "=", "yellow")

items.concat datastore.run(yellow_query)

items.each do |item|
   puts "Tags: #{item['tags']}"
end
```

The code:

```
query.where("tag", "=", colors[0]).where("tag", "=", colors[1])
```

could be misinterpreted as an OR operation, but it's an AND operation. [Source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/c4a5cb3e91f1952667c9fff6d6e1ac03cbefdbcf/google-cloud-datastore/lib/google/cloud/datastore/query.rb#L178-L195).

As pointed out by nshmura, the API doesn't support operators other than the AND operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that [ruby client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/google-cloud-datastore/v1.0.0/google-cloud-datastore) uses `GRPC API` or `REST API`, but each API dose not support `OR` operation.

- [Operator of GRPC API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rpc/google.datastore.v1#google.datastore.v1.PropertyFilter.Operator)
- [Operator of REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#Operator_1)

So I think `OR` operation is impossible.